# Can someone explain me this function

Tags: php

I am going through a PHP course on Udemy. In a chapter about "Anonymous Functions & Closures", there is some code that I didn't understand. I wrote a question about that to the author of the course, but I want to ask here on Stack Overflow as well.

```
<?php

// Closures and outer scope access
function createCounter()
{
  $count = 0;

  // Define a closure that captures the $count variable
  $counter = function () use (&$count) {
    return ++$count;
  };

  return $counter;
}

// Create a counter function
$counter = createCounter();

// Use the counter function to increment and display the count
echo $counter() . "\n"; // Output: 1
echo $counter() . "\n"; // Output: 2
echo $counter() . "\n"; // Output: 3
```

Why there is an output of `1,2,3` when in the function `createCounter()` the variable `$count` is always set to `0` in the beginning? I expected that the output would be `1,1,1`

I read this function several times, but I'm still not able to understand how this works in practice.

Comment: `in the function createCounter() the varable $count is always set to 0 in the beginning.` right, and you're calling `createCounter` only one time, so you initialize `$count` to 0 only one time, every time you call `$counter()` - it increases this variable and outputs value, you're calling it 3 times, so you're getting 1,2,3

Comment: `createCounter()` returns the anonymous function `$counter`, so every time you call `$counter()`, you're actually calling that anonymous function. The anonymous function uses the pointer to `$count` so it uses the initially defined variable instead of creating a new one each time. https://3v4l.org/gDEXV might help show what's going on.

Comment: The part that is throwing you off is `use (&$count)`, which uses a `reference` to `$count`, which means that the closure operates on the `$count` variable from the parent scope. Yeah, it's confusing.

Answer (score 0):

It's a rather obtuse example, and can be very confusing at first glance. Let's look at some of the moving parts here:

1. We have a function called `createCounter`. This function takes no arguments.
2. Inside of this function, a variable named `$count` is initialized with a value of `0`.
3. Inside of this function, a variable named `$counter` is set to an anonymous function. This function contains a reference to the previously mentioned `$count` variable, and when executed, increments this value.
4. The `createCounter` function `return`s the previously mentioned `$counter` anonymous function

With all of this in mind, the following line begins everything:

`$counter = createCounter();`

What is happening here? Well, the function named `createCounter` is called, an internal variable is initialized with a value of zero, another is set to an anonymous function that uses this variable as a reference and increments it when called. And it is this anonymous function that is returned.

On the next line, you'll see the following:

`echo $counter() . "\n";`

We have called the anonymous function returned by the `createCounter` function, which increments the internal `$count` reference by one. The `$count` reference is now equal to 1.

We see it executed again on the next line:

`echo $counter() . "\n";`

The same function is called, and the same internal reference is incremented yet again. The `$count` reference is now 2.

Repeating this same pattern again, we get a new value of 3.

Now, [let's modify this script a little](https://onlinephp.io/c/57d6c). We've added another call to the `createCounter` function and stored it in a separate variable. We then execute the returned closure another 3 times using that variable.

At first glance, what are you expecting the output to be? Are you expecting `4, 5, 6`? Or `1, 2, 3`?

> The answer is `1, 2, 3`! Remember, each call to `createCounter` creates a whole new `$count` variable in that particular function scope. So the closure within only contains that particular reference.

Once you start to wrap your head around function scope, closure scope, and references it should start to make a little more sense.

Hope this helps!